# Define statement being printed in output

Tags: php

I'm trying to define a constant for deployment proposes so that we know that we are on a development environment.

1. I've created a PHP file with:

   ```
   define('LDEV', true);
   ```

   And name it, for example: **devEnv.php**

   I've placed somewhere: ex: */home/user/Sites/devEnv.php*
2. In `php.ini`, I set my auto_prepend_file attribute to my file, like so:

   ```
   auto_prepend_file = "/Users/user/Sites/devEnv.php"
   ```
3. I restarted Apache to see the changes

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

Now I see this `define('LDEV', true);` echoed on my local site and it shouldn't be there.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you include the opening PHP tag in your include file?

Answer (score 7):

You need the PHP opening tag in the `devEnv.php` script:

```
<?php
define('LDEV', true);
```

Comment: psst.. don't tell anyone that I forgot it ok? :D thks. :)